# Как открыть PUSH уведомление в диалоговом окне

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления, push, firebase-android

Добрый день!

Использую Firebase для отправки PUSH уведомлений. Делаю все по инструкции. 
PUSH уведомления приходят прекрасно. Отправляем их через PHP код, не стандартную консоль.
Возник вопрос - как получить сообщение которое было в PUSH уведомлении во время открытия Activity?! Если приложение запущено то приложение попадает в FirebaseMessagingService, где я зашиваю уже в Intent само сообщение и во время открытия Activity получаю его и вывожу, но если приложение не запущено то FirebaseMessagingService не отрабатывает и просто запускается Activity.

Вот пример:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());


    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}


private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, main_activity.class).
            setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE", messageBody);

    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(main_activity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(requestID, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // only for gingerbread and newer versions
        MyNotificationHelper notificationHelper = new MyNotificationHelper(this);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = notificationHelper.getNotification1(pendingIntent, getString(R.string.notification_title_text), messageBody);

        if (notificationBuilder != null) {
            notificationHelper.notify(1, notificationBuilder);
        }

    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title_text))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_title_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если внимательно прочесть документацию, особенно раздел:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages
то можно узреть табличку, в каких случаях можно перехватывать сообщения в методе **onMessageReceived**.

Если вкратце, то для реализации Вашей задачи нужно использовать параметр Data и обязательно исключить параметр **body**, чтоб Вы всегда могли перехватить сообщение в **onMessageReceived**.

Описание всех доступных параметров можно найти на странице:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#data